# Is it possible for mysql to create a distributed database?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible for mysql to create a distributed database ?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_database

Comment: Please define "distributed database".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. Any large site like WordPress.com couldn't possibly hope to run their entire MySQL database off one server. They use replication and sharding to distribute the database over tens, hundreds, or thousands of servers.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your definition, but [MySQL Cluster](http://www.mysql.com/products/database/cluster/) may fit your need.

Answer (score 1):

You should had a look at TiDB. It's an open source MySQL compatible NewSQL HTAP database.

https://github.com/pingcap/tidb

Answer (score 0):

The [Clustrix Database](http://www.clustrix.com) is a distributed database built from the ground up to be a MySQL replacement. It has a shared nothing architecture and automatically distributes data and does [distributed query evaluation](http://docs.clustrix.com/display/CLXDOC/Evaluation+Model).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is possible to do this. You can certainly create a distributed (horizontally scaled) database with MySQL and the specific technique(s) used for this are related to parallel databases. To a lesser extent several people implement sharding style solutions that give you some of the benefits of horizontal scalability, but also place some limitations on them.